# Comments to different db entries

Tags: database, database-design

For example, I have "news" and "articles" tables and I want comment these entries using "comments" table.

[image]

What the best way to make relationship and comment different entries?

Comment: Are comments separate (i.e. a comment can be only for an article or a news entry .. not both) ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "comment these entries?" Are your comments data about who edited the entry (for example), or do you mean actual comments by users related to your news and articles?

Comment: Aziz, I have thought to do new comment table for each entry, but count of tables may be more then 2, but "comments" tables will be equals.

Comment: Bryan, I mean users will be allowed to comment news and articles. For example, like an answer on the question on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume both news and articles to comments are one-to-many . And I also assume the same comment cannot associate to a new and an article at the same time.

One of the way is that:

[image]

Advantages is that the Schema is normalized  ,data integrity is properly maintained and it allows for schema evolution. For example , there may be possibility to add the comment for another similar kind of entity in the future (eg Allow adding comments for the blog table).

Disadvantages is that it requires  join extra table when query the comments for a news or articles